# IOS7 Subviews get animated if their parent view is being animated

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, ios7

I had a very strange bug with some of my views when I started testing against iOS7. It appears that if any of the properties that can be animated, changes its value in subview, while its parent is going through animation, the change also gets animated. I have the following method:

```
- (void)performAnimation{
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.42
                         delay:0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                    animations:^{
                     self.myView.contentInset = contentInset;
                 }
                 completion:NULL];
}
```

In the meantime my layoutsubviews function on that view is called and it updates the position of some of the subviews.

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
      self.someSubview.frame = CGRectMake(10,20,30,40);
}
```

In iOS5/6 the change was happening instantaneous but in iOS7 it gets animated so you can see my subview slowly moving from its initial place to its final position. Any thoughts?

Comment: A little bit weird is that you animate `contentInset`. It's not animatable due to: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html

Comment: Do you use `autolayout` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to figure it out. In IOS7 they have introduced a new function

[+ (void)performWithoutAnimation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)

I simply wrapped my code in layoutSubviews in it and the unwanted animation disappeared.

Comment: Awesome stuff, I've had a similar problem with new animation jitters in iOS 7 when a bunch of views are being moved. Had to do the same thing and take a couple of changes and remove the animations from them.